# Ferramenta de auxilio na configuração Postgresql . conf

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, configuração

alguém sabe alguma ferramenta que auxilia no ajuste dos parâmetros do
arquivo postgresql.conf.

Já fiz uso do [PGTUNE](http://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/)  e do [PGConfig](https://www.pgconfig.org), mas eles não indicam nada
dos parâmetros:

- cpu_tuple_cost
- cpu_index_tuple_cost
- cpu_operator_cost
- seq_page_cost
- random_page_cost

Eu estou com o problema relatado no outro post: 
[Porque estimativas de custos no PostgreSQL erram tanto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/231401/porque-estimativas-de-custos-no-postgresql-erram-tanto), em que o otimizador
está sempre escolhendo fazer full-scan ao invés de estrategias
indexada por exemplo.
Entendo que as vezes realmente é mais ágil fazer full-scan do que sair
percorrendo um índice, que exige acesso aleatório, mas testei também
com discos SSDs , alterando random_page_cost = 1, e continuou
acontecendo o problema (custo incorretos) e  estrategias indexadas,
serem menos eficientes que sem indices. Penso que devo ajustar esses
parametros melhor. Se tiverem alguma dica de ferramenta ou outra
forma, por favor retornem.